# grunt-processhtml correct use

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

Ok guys, Im trying to understand this but I cant find any basic tutorials.

I have uncss, this is my basic task

```
 uncss: {
            dist: {
                src: ['about.htm', 'index.htm'],
                dest: 'css/tidy.css',
                options: {
                    report: 'min' // optional: include to report savings
                }
            }
        }
```

next I have grunt-processhtml, I am trying to write a task to replace all css in index.htm

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/some.css">
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/somemore.css">
```

and turn it into

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tidy.css">
```

Im not sure how to do this, I know I use grunt-processhtml like

```
processhtml: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'index.html': ['index.html'],
      'about.html': ['about.html']
    }
  }
}
```

but how do I replace all

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/some.css">
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/somemore.css">
```

with my new tidy.css ?

Please guys, I need some basic help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [grunt-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml) you can use the following to output the CSS links according to the environment. I am not sure how to define the environment though (check the documentation).

If it's `dist` the tidy.css file will be created alreay and it will be linked

```
<!-- build:template
<% if (environment === 'dev') { %>
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/some.css">
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/somemore.css">
<% } else { %>
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tidy.css">
<% } %>
/build -->
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, so i post that code in my css, change the directories to match mine then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [grunt-string-replace](https://github.com/eruizdechavez/grunt-string-replace).

I use it for srcset, because grunt-processhtm can't handle multiple sourceset attributes. E.g.:

```
<img srcset="../img/img_one_400.jpg 400w,
  ../img/img_one_600.jpg 600w,
  ../img/img_one_1200.jpg 1200w,
  ../img/img_one_1408.jpg 1408w"
  sizes="100vw"
  src="../img/img_one_1408.jpg"/>
```

configuration in the Gruntfile.js:

```
'string-replace': {
        inline: {
            files: {
                'build/pages/': 'build/pages/*.html'
            },
            options: {
                replacements:[
                    {
                        //../img/ -> recources/img/
                        pattern: /\.\.\/img\//g,
                        replacement: 'fileadmin/img/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
[...]
            options: {
                replacements:[
                    {
                        pattern: /\/css\/some\.css/g,
                        replacement: '/css/tidy.css'
                    }
                ]
            }
[...]
```